# Getting the value of Props parameter as undefined (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, web-frontend

I'm having an attribute in one of the components and when I'm trying to access that attribute via props, I'm getting its value as undefined.

**Below is the piece of code where I'm making use of the component and passing the required attribute.**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PageNotFound from "./pages/page-not-found";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import BookSectionPage from "./pages/books-section";
import BookDetails from "./pages/book-details";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={BookSectionPage}/>
            <Route path="/book/category/:categoryName" exact render = { (props) => {
              return <BookSectionPage title = "JavaScript" /> // This is the component
            }} />
            <Route path="/book/:bookID" exact component={BookDetails} />
            <Route component={PageNotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Below is the code for the component where I'm trying to access the above-mentioned attribute via Props but getting its value as undefined.**

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "../components/header/header";
import Footer from "../components/Footer/footer";
import BookSectionComponent from "../components/books-section/books-section";

const BookSectionPage = (Props) => {
  let books=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
  console.log(Props.title);     // Here instead of printing the value of attribute, it's showing undefined. 
  return (
    <div className="has-fixed-footer">
      <Header />
      <BookSectionComponent title = {Props.title} books = {books} />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default BookSectionPage;
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try this. Const title = {name: "sometitle"}, then <yourcomponent title={title}/>

Comment: In which phase you passing the prop `title` to `BookSectionPage`?

Comment: @LogeshP tried it, unfortunately, no success.

Comment: @DennisVash the first piece of code that I have given above is where I'm passing the attribute to the component (I have written some comment for the reference) and then the second piece of code is the code of the component where I'm trying to access the attribute via Props.

Comment: Try removing props in main component

Comment: @AnmolSarraf can you create a stackblitz with your code?

Answer (score 0):

From Parent to Child Using Props

```
App
└── Parent
    ├── Child1
```

Most easiest direction of data flow in React and basic example.

## Parent Component

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
state = { title : "JavaScript" } 
render() {

        return (
            <div>           
                 <Child1 dataFromParent = {this.state.title} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

## Child Component

```
class Child1 extends React.Component {
render() {

        return (
            <div>
                The data from parent is:{this.props.dataFromParent}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```